# convert string to 2d arrayList

Tags: java, arraylist

I have a string `2d` array, I am trying to convert it to `ArrayList` of `ArrayList` of `string` i.e. 
 `ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>` I tried to convert it but no luck

Here is my string

```
"RawMatrixData": "[[1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8]]"
```

And the output I want:

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> myList = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();
myList = [[1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8]];//it must be list not string
```

Your solution will be highly appreciated.

Comment: *I tried to convert it but no luck* - can you share your attempt(s) please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, the easiest way if you use the jackson ObjectMapper. Add dependency to com.fasterxml.jackson.

```
String data = "[[1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8]]";

ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> list  = objectMapper.readValue(data, ArrayList.class);
```

Comment: can you please share the link of  jackson ObjectMapper

Comment: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-databind/2.9.7